# Navigation using path parameter on Pretty Faces 2.0.8.Final

Tags: prettyfaces

Consider the configuration below:

```
@URLMapping(id = "programaManter", parentId = "homeTreinamento", pattern = "/programa/#{id : programaManter.id}", viewId = "/pages/treinamento/ProgramaManter.xhtml")
```

Lets say that I need to navigate to **/programa/1**. I've tried the following:

```
return "/pages/treinamento/ProgramaManter.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&id=" + id;
```

But instead of navigating to **/programa/1** it's navigating to **/programa/?id=1**, how can I force it to build the url using path parameter instead of query parameter?

Comment: This is a strange issue. Could you try upgrading to 2.0.10.Final and see if that resolves the problem? It looks like what you are doing should work, but if this doesn't help. Maybe you could provide us a sample project that reproduces the issue on our support forums: http://ocpsoft.org/support/ Thanks!

Comment: I've tried it on 2.0.10 and the result was the same. I will provide a sample project ASAP. It's not a major problem though. I will use query parameter as a work around.

Comment: Done: http://ocpsoft.org/support/topic/navigation-using-path-parameter-on-pretty-faces-2-0-8-final/

Answer (score 1):

Solution posted here on the OCPsoft support forums: http://ocpsoft.org/support/topic/navigation-using-path-parameter-on-pretty-faces-2-0-8-final/#post-25822